# bazel: set c++ flags for all project depending on os/compiler

Tags: c++, compilation, bazel

Recently I wanted to migrate all my projects to bazel and finally I am building them with command setting c++ standard manually for different operations systems:

```
bazel build //... --cxxopt=-std=c++17 --compilation_mode opt
bazel build //... --cxxopt=/std:c++17 --compilation_mode opt
```

I would set it in `.bzl` file but setting standard is different for linux and windows, so I will anyway need to override it with `--cxxopt=/std:c++17` for MSVC.
I tried to add global variable to `.bzl` file and load it for all projects, e.g.:

```
# variables.bzl
COPTS = ["-std=c++17"]
```

This works (but as I mentioned before it will anyway require changing for different platforms).
Then I've tried:

```
# variables.bzl
COPTS = select({
        "//tools/cc_target_os:windows": ["/std:c++17"],
        "//conditions:default": ["-std=c++17"],
})
```

But it lead to error:

```
ERROR: path/to/project/BUILD:2:1: no such package 'tools/cc_target_os': BUILD file not found on package path and referenced by '//project:smth'
```

Is it possible to set c++ flags to all projects depending on platform (compiler)?
Unfortunately, I could not find any working example.
Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows` instead.

```
# variables.bzl
COPTS = select({
        "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:windows": ["/std:c++17"],
        "//conditions:default": ["-std=c++17"],
})
```

Comment: This is going to cause problems with MinGW and cross builds.